# What's the difference between plain image source url with string vs using the URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, image, api, object, url

I saw this code earlier and have never seen it. I am wondering how it differs from setting the image source to a url string?

```
function displayImage(blob) {
  let objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = objectURL;
  document.body.appendChild(image); 
}
```

What is the URL API commonly used for?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is on where is the *resource* that both URLs point to.

In the case of an `http[s]://` URL, the *resource* will be stored on a server, and the browser will be able to simply fetch it from there using an HTTP request.

In the case of a `blob://` URL, the *resource* will either be in memory, or on user's disk.
So there, the browser can't use the same simple HTTP request to fetch the *resource*, there is no server at the other end able to respond correctly to such a request.

So `blob://` URIs were made to create a new protocol, where browsers will be able to mimic such a request, allowing everything that does normally *fetch* resources to also fetch these special resources, but this time, not with an HTTP request, since there is no server.

You can create `blob://` URIs from a few different sources which will all induce a few fundamental differences.

- From a File served by an <input type="file"> or similar, the *resource* stays on the user's disk and the `blob://` URI is a direct pointer to that *resource*.
- From a generated Blob or File, the *resource* stays in the memory and the `blob://` URI is a direct pointer to that *resource*. As long as the URI is alive, the *resource* can't be collected by the GarbageCollector, so don't forget to revoke it when not used anymore.
- From a MediaSource, the *resource* is the MediaSource's internal data, thus in memory, but not as persistent as with Blobs, since the browser can clear the buffer when it wants.

Note also that there are `file://` URIs, which also points to *resources* on the user's disk, but here, it's more the OS that plays the role of server, with a lot of restrictions.